# Optimize performance java "for" and "array string"

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I had problems with the slowness of this code.
I tried to optimize it for make it faster but I could not.
Can you give me some suggestions?

This is the part of the java code:

```
public ArrayList<String> kcal_spu(String tipo_pasto, String data) {

        kcal_spuntino = new ArrayList<String>();
        id_cibi_colazione = DiarioDataBaseAdapter.getId(tipo_pasto, data);
        porzione_n2_colazione = DiarioDataBaseAdapter.getPorzione(tipo_pasto, data);
        ArrayList<?> kcal2 = DiarioDataBaseAdapter.getKcal2(tipo_pasto, data);
        int size = id_cibi_colazione.size();
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            double num_porz = Double.parseDouble(porzione_n2_colazione.get(j));
            String getkcal = FoodDataBaseAdapter.getKcal(id_cibi_colazione.get(j));
            String id_check = id_cibi_colazione.get(j);
            if (id_check.equals("null")) {
                double kcal_porz = Double.parseDouble(kcal2.get(j).toString());
                double result = num_porz * kcal_porz;
                kcal_spuntino.add("" + (int) result);
                j = j + 1;
            } else {
                double kcal_porz = Double.parseDouble(getkcal);
                double result = num_porz * kcal_porz;
                kcal_spuntino.add("" + (int) result);
                j = j + 1;
            }
        }


        return kcal_spuntino;
    }
```

This is the function DiarioDataBaseAdapter.getId:

```
public ArrayList getId(String tipo_pasto, String data) {
    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT ID_CIBO from Diario_Cibo where TIPO_PASTO = '" + tipo_pasto + "' AND DATA = '" + data + "'", null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ID_CIBO")));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    if (res != null) {
        res.close();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

This is the function DiarioDataBaseAdapter.getPorzione:

```
public ArrayList getPorzione(String tipo_pasto, String data) {
    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT PORZIONE from Diario_Cibo where TIPO_PASTO = '" + tipo_pasto + "' AND DATA = '" + data + "'", null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("PORZIONE")));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    if (res != null) {
        res.close();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

This is the function DiarioDataBaseAdapter.getKcal2:

```
public ArrayList getKcal2(String tipo_pasto, String data) {
    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT KCAL from Diario_Cibo where TIPO_PASTO = '" + tipo_pasto + "' AND DATA = '" + data + "'", null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("KCAL")));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    if (res != null) {
        res.close();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try profiling this code? May be the database operations time may dominate the total execution time and optimization of code might not result in much gain.

Comment: Might be more appropriate for CodeReview than StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database queries will be the slowest part and there are three of them. Without profiling the code I would start with looking at the database selects and the tables to make sure they have the correct indexes on them for efficient searching.

Otherwise even putting a simple nanosecond timer in the code will give you an idea of what is taking the most time.

eg.

[System.nanoTime():](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// do stuff
long end = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("time " + (end -start));
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.
How can I create the index table in order to optimize the search?

Comment: I would profile first before doing that to see if that is the issue using the simple nanosecond timer method. The Primary key of your table will already have an index. This link will help: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp

Comment: Ok now i profile the code and I inform you of where the time consuming.

Comment: Ok that will be interesting, let us know the figures.